# How to Call a function from a class in Visual Studio Solution

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

Now to working with Visual Studio Solutions, but I am trying something very basic but no joy.

So in my project I have a folder App_Code and in this I added a class called Test.vb

and added a simple function

```
Public Class Test2
Public Function ReplaceXSS(ByVal InputString As String) As String
    InputString = InputString.Replace("<script>", "")
    InputString = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(InputString)
    InputString = InputString.Replace("</script>", "")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("&", "&#38;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("<", "&#60;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace(">", "&#62;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("%", "&#37;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("|", "&#124;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("$", "&#36;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("'", "&#39;")
    InputString = InputString.Replace("""", "&#92;")

    ReplaceXSS = InputString
End Function
```

End Class

But in my Default.aspx page I am struggling to find the correct syntax to call this method.

Also it doesnt seem like my Test2.vb class is correctly included in the project because If I make a type the project still builds successfully when it shouldnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you Test2 is under some namespace, that's you are unable to make object of that class. You have to mention the namespace before class name `Dim test As New NameSpace.Test2`

```
Dim test As New Test2 ' Make an object of that class
test.ReplaceXSS(Parameters.....) ' access the method
```

Comment: I get Error 102 Type 'Test2' is not defined. C:\inetpub\wwwroot\United Drug\Default.aspx.vb 5 26 United Drug
Seems like it cant find that Test2 for some reason

Comment: I guess you have namespace in your Test2 class, Can you paste complete code of Test2.vb that is in app code?

Comment: Ok heres the lowdown I again tried a brand new class by going right click "Add" "Add New Class" blah blah and the above worked which is cool. But when I add new class to a folder which I imported to this project it does not work

Comment: And the code for both class works fine but depending on wether I create it the root or in my App_Code folder it works or doesnt. The question is how can I getting a new class working in this App_Code Folder.

Comment: That's what I have told you in the first comment, Its the namespace that's why you could not get that class. It should be like, if you have namespace Dim test As New NameSpaceName.Test2

Comment: Hey Muhammad, not sure what you mean by namespace i.e. I Tried Dim test3 As New App_Code.Spurs2 but still cant find it

Comment: Whenever you place a class in a folder, the folder name must prefix the class name.

Comment: Can you please paste all what you have in your Test2.vb ?

Comment: Hey Muhammad see my original post thats it

Comment: I have already seen your original post, I have test the same its working to me. I can only think one problem that is namespace, just read some thing from google about namespace concept.

Comment: Muhammad when you tried it, did you also add it to a subfolder that seems to be the problem.

Comment: @StevieB - Perhaps download something such as Resharper or Coderush. It will find your class and add the appropriate namespace

Comment: Just trying to find out why these namespaces so complex. So i.e. my .net page is called Default.aspx. My Class is in a folder called App_Code. How can I reference this class in the Default.aspx.vb ?

Comment: Dim test As New NameSpaceName.Test2

Comment: Hey Muhammad, cool I get that now, but im wondering how I can find out what the NameSpaceName is. I tried my site Name Space United_Site.Test2 which didnt work. I also tried adding the folder name i.e. United_Drug.App_Code.Test2 which also didnt work

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you have a reference to the project that houses `Test2`. After you have a reference, you should be able to:

```
Dim MyTest2 As New Test2
```

If you still cannot instantiate an instance of the object, make sure there is no namespace you defined. If there is, prefix Test2 with the name of the namespace plus a dot.

Comment: Basically the difference seems to be when I add a class to a folder which I imported to this solution, the class doesnt seem to work. But when I add to root of solution it works fine. The folder where I want to create my class is called App_Code but they dont seem to work in this one

Comment: @StevieB - This is an ASP.NET project?